# Как добавить CSS стиль до @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsComplete , new { @class = "checkbox" })
```

Css код:

```
.сheckbox{
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ed495c;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: background 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Ничего не изменилось.Меняется только тогда, когда :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style="width:100px;height:25px" })
```

Comment: Где находится этот файл css? Он подключен к view? [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-6.0), [Layout in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov он в wwwroot